# Is the Electrical Power dissipated in a resistor with zero resistance equals to infinity or zero?

Tags: electric-circuits, electricity, electrical-resistance, power

Consider a simple circuit consisted of an energy source with constant voltage and a resistor with zero resistance .
According to equation for Electrical Power dissipated in a resistor : *$P=V^2/R$* where (*V*=Voltage , *R*=Resistance , *P*=Power)
Now if we substitute *$0$* into *R* we get that *P* is equal to *$\infty$* .
But if the resistance is zero then there should be no loss of electrical energy and thus *P* should be equal to zero but this contradicts with the resault seen before that *P* is equal to *$\infty$*.
So where am I wrong ? and is P equal to *$0$* or to *$\infty$* ? what is the mathmatical and physical explanations of this ?
~Thanks in advance

Comment: If R is zero then V must also be zero according to Ohm's law.

Comment: @Solomon Slow : Let's assume the power source is non-zero and the current in the circuit can become infinity

Comment: Physics doesn't like infinities. Any time you find one, you're either trying to describe an [unphysical](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/unphysical) situation, or else you're talking about some real phenomenon (e.g., the fate of matter that falls in to a black hole) for which physics simply has no appropriate theory. In this case, it's the former: It's unphysical. There is no reason to suspect that an infinitely powerful voltage source could exist, and that makes it unlikely that you'll get any Physicist interested in talking about it.

Comment: @Solomon Slow : you can still consider a resistor with very low resistance that approaches zero and a very high current that approaches infinity and equals to V/R

Comment: You can _consider_ it, but what actual, physical power supply is going to maintain a constant voltage V when you short it out?

Comment: If you insist on changing the conditions so that every answer is not what you want, then you should expect people to down vote your question.  Or possibly even close it.

Comment: @Dan : I don't care about votes and don't care if my question get closed , I just want to know why the lower the resistance the higher the power and no answer has answered the question every answer went on why my circuit doesn't exist in practice .

Answer (score 1):

Mathematically, you shouldn't think about setting R to zero but rather taking the limit as R goes to zero. If you're unfamiliar with calculus, you can imagine dividing R by two over and over again. Every time the resistance gets smaller, P goes up, as you notice from $P=V^2/R$. Ohm's law stops making sense when you just plug in $R=0$, unless $V$ is also zero.

**Bonus: what goes wrong with Ohm's law?**
In a real resistor, the electric field (coming from $V$) accelerates the electrons, and the electrons scatter (bounce) off of defects in the conductor, slowing them down and producing heat. Ohm's law applies when these two competing effects balance out, and the electrons reach a steady state average velocity. If R were truly zero, then there would be no scattering/heat production, but also nothing to stop the electrons from accelerating forever. So current would keep increasing with time and I would not simply be proportional to V. This is more-or-less what happens inside particle accelerators!

Comment: Maybe my question was badly stated but what I meant is that according to the equation given the power source provide constant voltage then the lower the resistance the higher the power dissipated so why this happens ?

Comment: I guess the short answer is that as you decrease resistance while holding voltage constant, current increases, as a result of $V=IR$. The more 'fundamental' equation for power is $P=IV$, which holds for other circuit elements like capacitors and inductors. From this you can see that as $I$ goes up, so does $V$. Feel free to reply if that still doesn't answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

> Now if we substitute *$0$* into *R* we get that *P* is equal to
> *$\infty$* .

No.

Mathematical Explanation:

Mathematically, we can say that the solution for $x/y$ is a number that, when multiplied by $y$ will give you $x$. But "infinity" is not a number. It is a concept meaning endless or boundless. That means dividing a non zero number by zero is "undefined", because it is a quantity that is not defined or does not exist.

Similarly, if we replace the $V$ by $IR$ per Ohm's law, we get $0/0$. In this case the solution is "indeterminate" since any number multiplied by zero (the denominator) will give you zero (the numerator). Mathematically "indeterminate" means it is a quantity having no definite or definable value.

For further discussions of undefined and indeterminate quantities, see

From:[http://5010.mathed.usu.edu/Fall2018/LPierson/indeterminateandundefined.html#:~:text=Indeterminate%3Ahaving%20a%20quantity%20with,defined%20or%20does%20not%20exist](http://5010.mathed.usu.edu/Fall2018/LPierson/indeterminateandundefined.html#:%7E:text=Indeterminate%3Ahaving%20a%20quantity%20with,defined%20or%20does%20not%20exist).

Physical Explanation:

With the exception of superconductors, which do not dissipate heat, all real conductors have resistance. So, with the exception of superconductors, $R\ne0$ and Power has a defined value.

In the case of superconductors where $R=0$ no power is dissipated for any value of current.

Hope this helps.

Comment: But let's say the resistance is very very low then according to the equation mentioned in my Original Post the Power dissipated will be very high so why is that ?

Comment: @NazareneChristianSoldier The problem is there is no such thing as a "constant voltage source". All real voltage sources have source impedance. Real batteries have internal resistance. The lower you make the load resistance the greater the voltage drop across the source resistance which in turn puts a practical limit on the amount of power dissipated in the load resistance

Answer (score 0):

There is no power source with zero inner resistance, so if you short circuit the power source  it depends on this resistance , what energy output you get.

Comment: Lets assume we have an ideal battery and a resistor with very very low resistance then according to the equation the power dissipated will be very high why is that ?

Comment: the batterie will be uncharged in very short time and get very hot, maybe better don't try it.Or first calculate the hear you get per second

Answer (score 0):

What kind of source do you have ? And what connectors do you have ?

If it is a battery, it has a nonzero proper resistance. The current when you short-circuit it with your "zero resistance" resistor will not depend on **its**  resistance, but on the battery's proper resistance. The current will be large, it will rapidly empty the battery and probably destroy it on the way. But this huge but finite current will dissipate all the energy in the battery itself, and zero (or very little) in your resistor.

If you have a powerful power line directly connected to your resistor, forcing a finite voltage (220V or 110V) on its ends. Then the current will be huge, finite voltage divided by extremely small resistance, and your "almost" zero resistor will absorb a huge electrical power, finite forced voltage multiplied by huge current and will melt, or explode.

If you have a powerful power line directly connected to your apartment, and you short-circuit one electric plug with your zero resistor, you'll have 220V (or 110) at the entrance of your apartment, because the company will provide it. But zero voltage between the ends of your conductor, so the voltage drop will happen in the electric wiring of your apartment and start a fire. Only your "zero resistance" resistor might survive.

Comment: I understand that this can't exist in practical sense but I want to assume theoretically that we have an ideal battery and a resistor with very very low resistance and that resistor can have any current without being affected then why the resistor dissipate very high energy(according to the equation) although it has very low resistance and thus not much heat generated because of it ?

Comment: For an ideal battery (or rather, ideal Electrical Company, that guarantees 220V whatever the current you use, then, the lower the resistance, the higher the current. Power creation is voltage (FIXED) times current (HIGHER the lower the resistance is) thus the lower the resistance, the higher the power used, and when the resistance goes to zero, the power goes to infinity. But the point is that an "ideal" Electrical Company does not exist either ! Above some level of demand for power, the production of electricity won't be able to follow.